# .NET Core 2.0 - BlogCategory from BlogItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Just trying to get my `@item.BlogCategories.CategoryName` to display the Category,
but it says the object is not set. I checked the DB. and the `BlogCategoryId` is correct. If this was MVC5 it wouldn't be a problem. whats different in MVC core?

it writes the rest of the `@items` correct, `@item.Title`,id etc.

---

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
<a href="#">@item.BlogCategories.CategoryName</a>
```

---

```
public class BlogItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string BodyText { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ImageTag> Tags { get; set; }

    public int BlogCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogCategory BlogCategories { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
    private readonly BlogDbContext db;

    public HomeController(BlogDbContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }
    #endregion
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<BlogItem> bi = db.BlogItems.OrderByDescending(m => m.DateCreated).ToList();
        return View(bi);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entity Framework Core doesn't do lazy loading (at least, [not yet](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap#stretch-goals)) so you need to be explicit about the child properties you need. For example:

```
List<BlogItem> bi = db.BlogItems
    .Include(bi => bi.BlogCategory)
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.DateCreated)
    .ToList();
```